# How to pull images from network share to InDesign that works in both Windows and OSX?

Tags: macos, windows-7, sitecore, adobe-indesign

We are running a project where we use a CMS (Sitecore) to feed InDesign with content to dynamically create a product catalog.

In short we create components in Sitecore that then can be dragged into InDesign and be connected to a certain page in the CMS. We then pull images from the CMS into the InDesign document.

The problem:
On the product pages we fetch images from a network share instead of the CMS. And we do so from a network link in the format `\\ip\folder\file.jpg` This works great in our Windows environment but not at all in OSX.

From what I understand the `\\ip\folder\file.jpg` format is a windows specific one, so we have also tried the `smb://ip/folder/file.jpg` format without luck. The SMB-path actually crashes both the windows and mac version of InDesign.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Feedback from sitecore:

- Add server as network share in Finder. (eg smb://192.169.0.100)
- Extend the user profile in sitecore so we can set the user to be a OSX or windows user.
- If user is mac, output path as `folder:subfolder:file.jpg`
- If user is PC, output path as `\\192.168.0.100\folder\subfolder\file.jpg`